# Missing cancel button when editing some audit review questions/answers reveals it is an audit review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

If you perform a "first posts" review of a question, and you use the "edit" link below the question, then for a question that is NOT a review audit, you'll get a message above the question that looks like so:

> This is the first question asked by a new user. Help them learn to use the site by reviewing their post

To the right of this question, there is a button "editing", and a link to "cancel" your edit.

However for a question that is actually a review audit question, of a high quality post, there is no such message (and related editing button / cancel link). So for such kind of review questions, just hitting the edit link, is a way to discover that it is actually a review audit of a high quality question (just cancel the edit session, and select "no action needed", and you passed the review audit).

I doubt that is the intended design, which is why IMO it is to be considered as an undocumented feature (aka a *bug* that became a feature ...) to discover these kind of review audits. My recommendation (not more then that) for a possible fix, is that for such review audits the same message (and editing button / cancel link) should be shown also.

**Notes**:

- So far I've never failed a review audit about a question that was actually considered as **spam**. And for such kinds of review audits, I never waste my time to even consider hitting the edit button. So consider such spam questions as out-of-scope for my question here.

  However, to further investigate (experiment with) such a case, I just ran into a first post review which was actually an answer, which IMO definitely looked like spam. This is what the entire answer looked like (with 2 links in it intentionally not repeated here):

  > Right clic or Modify multilevel list and Start at: 1 wordexperto

  After I hit the "edit" link, I got a message like "*This post is deleted and cannot be edited.*". Next I used the back button, and further completed the review (= flagged it), but for sure I did NOT fail the audit because of using that "edit"-link.
- For review audits about questions that are actually to be considered as **low quality**, I'm assuming that those are the questions that result in a message like "*This post is deleted and cannot be edited.*" (since such posts are actually marked as deleted, I have no way of verifying if they were considered/marked as low quality).
- Sometimes the message like "*This post is deleted and cannot be edited.*" is wrong ... [This First Posts review](https://serverfault.com/review/first-posts/344710) is an example: you get such mesage if you use the edit link during the review of it, though if later on you revisit that very same link it turns out to be (at least right now ...) a closed question, not a deleted question ... (not sure if I should report this as a new question/bug ...).
- For "First posts" reviews of an answer (instead of a question), a similar issue seems to exists (if it is actually a review audit answer).

Comment: If it's a spam/low quality audit, then I think trying to edit reveals it's an audit a different way... by failing you.

Comment: @Laurel you ***think***, are you ***are sure***? Also, only "trying to edit", or after you try to save/submit the edited revision? FYI: I'm about sure for such audits you only get some "post was deleted" msg, but you do not fail the audit.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens That only applies to spam - and it's when you try to edit, not when you submit.

Comment: Despite my best efforts to forget, I did fail an audit when I tried to edit it once. I don't remember what queue, but it was an answer (that was plagiarized).

Comment: @Laurel my question is about a "question", not an "answer" (as in your lst comment). You may also want to review the notes I added to my question (partially as per your prior comments, to further clarify things).

Answer (score 3):

If you're paying so much attention that you notice a missing button: mission accomplished.

Audits are there to make sure you're giving the review your full attention - not just clicking "no action needed" for every post. If you see minor UI changes, you're doing well.

Comment: Please note the "*there is no such message (and related editing button / cancel link*" phrase in my question, so it's not just the button that's missing (actually the entire message is missing, and the surronding markup). So it hardly requires "*paying any attention*" to notice it's such review audit. Understand my point?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens my point stands - audits are there to make sure you’re not just clicking continue. You clearly aren’t - you noticed this difference.