# Does edit of an audit review question/answer now always result in a failed audit?

Tags: support, review-audits

Over the past week or so, on some SE site, I failed an audit review. And this happened after I used the "edit" link during such review. It was about a terribly formatted question, so I used the "edit" link to be able to read the source of it.

To double check what I seemed to have noticed, later on I (intentially) repeated a similar "edit" during a similar review (which I recognized as an audit review also, sorry for "testing" in production ...). And sure enough: I also failed that audit review.

So I suspect that what I asked about before, in "[Missing cancel button when editing some audit review questions/answers reveals it is an audit review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302368/286501)" (still tagged with [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) right now), no longer applies.

I cannot find any kind of announcement (or question tagged with [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits)) about this change in such reviews, hence my question:
***Does edit of an audit review question/answer now always result in a failed audit?***

Comment: `<snark-mode-on>` If you don't agree with the majority vote, you are wrong. That's what automated audit "majority->correct-answer" generation implies.`<snark-mode-off>`

Comment: @DWin I don't understand your comment, want to try again?

Comment: This happened to me to on SO just yesterday. Same situation: poorly formatted question, tapping "Edit" immediately failed the audit. This has to be a fairly recent change; previously, submitting a suggested edit would pass the audit.