# Why do you fail audit by using the edit link while viewing is allowed?

Tags: support, review-audits

Apart of what I described in [Does edit of an audit review question/answer now always result in a failed audit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310055/286501), I now noticed that it is still OK to *browse* a question during an audit review (by just clicking the hyperlink of the question). By that I mean: you do not (repeat: do not) fail the audit review using such browse. If however you would have used the *edit* link (below the question or answer that the audit review is about), you'll right away get the *Stop and listen ...* (aka you failed the audit).

Sure I understand (and agree) that one still has to be allowed/able to somehow browse a question related to the post (question or answer) to be reviewed. E.g. to discover answers during a review that simply repeat something already contained in another answer. If however you perform such browse to double check if maybe you're processing an audit review, such browse is a kind of making things complicated, because there is a much easier alternative for that: [Viewing vote counts while reviewing immediately unmasks review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311570/286501)

However I don't get that using either link (browse or edit) results in a different audit review result. It would make more sense to me that one should (only) fail the audit review by using the edit link, at the moment you try to save the edit (too bad if you spend some time to improve the post, that's what you get if you run into a failed audit).

Comment: and bonus points if you fail because you wanted to examine the post markdown since you were fearing that it may contain wrongly formatted / un-displayed content. I think this specific case was already lamented in the past.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I think your comment is similar to the "*...terribly formatted question...*" in my related (linked) question, no?

Comment: And, if you have 1k, you can also try to check the scores of the question. I think, audit questions should be invisible for everybody (including 10k+), at least until the audit lasts.

Comment: @peterh: what do you mean by that "check the scores of the question", how to do so? does it require you to click any link, or is it something you see on the review page itself? Maybe you just mean "the voting balance of the post being reviewed"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens If you have 1000 on that site, then clicking the voting score (for example, "3" for your this question) shows the count of the up and downvotes for that question. For deleted posts, it can't happen.

Comment: @peterh now I get it, you mean voting balance (= upvotes minus downvotes), so merci! BTW: in your first comment here, it should rather say "posts" (= question or answer) instead of "question" ... I think.